# Is it possible to use manage secrets feature of Visual Studio with Azure Service fabric

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to use manage secrets feature of Visual Studio with Azure Service fabric

I created an Stateless ASP.net core service fabric project. I moved some of the configs to secret.json but it does not seem to pick it up from there. It always seems to pickup from appsetting.json.

This is i am assuming due to the fact i am mentioning appsetting.json at startup

```
return new WebHostBuilder()
                                    .UseKestrel()
                                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                                        {
                                            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                                        })
                                    .ConfigureServices(
                                        services => services
                                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                    .UseUrls(url)
                                    .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-howto-manage-secrets

For this guidance about how to use/inject secrets in your application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-howto-manage-secrets#modify-mesh-application-to-reference-mesh-secret-values

For how to declare secret resources correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-howto-manage-secrets#declare-a-mesh-secrets-resource

You can add `var secretPath = PathHelper.GetSecretsPathFromSecretsId(typeof(Program).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<UserSecretsIdAttribute>().UserSecretsId);` to your app to see where that stores your secret configs.

It would look like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\
```